# What is the correct procedure to chant Narasimha 32 letters maha mantra?

Tags: avatars, practice, mantras, narasimha, vedic-chanting

The correct Narasimha maha mantra with 32 letters is:

उग्रं वीरं महाविष्णुं
ज्वलन्तं सर्वतोमुखं ।
नृसिंहं भीषणं भद्रं
मृत्युमृत्युं   नमाम्यहं ।।

Please note that a screenshot from Nrisimha Tapani Upanishad [image: is attached] which acts as a proof that above mantra is correct. But the thing which I don't know this is the correct procedure of chanting this mantra. Also find the [youtube link](https://youtu.be/XLX7OQPTE_c) which shows chanting of above mantra by Shri Mukkur swamy and also a group of slokas where all the 32 letters are put one by one.

Comment: You want pronunciation or process ?

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I want to learn the process or procedure of chanting this mantra like when to chant, if this mantra can be chanted anytime and anywhere ( pure or impure state), initiation required or not. Please let me know if you have this information. Thanks in advance :).

Comment: yes you can chant mentally whenever you like. In crisis or tough situations. For all mantras usually initiation is required so this is no exception.so try to find someone who has done decent upasana. So that mantra will be giving you better results.

Comment: Thanks. This particular Mantra doesnot starts with OM or beej Mantra. Are you sure initiation is required? If you can give me Shastra evidence that proves this point I will be very thankful to you. It is very difficult to find a person who is a very good upasak of Narasimha God. I don't have any Guru as well.

Comment: If you do not learn to pronounce correctly, it can have the opposite effect. You should learn in person from a competent person. Trying to learn on the internet will only lead to mispronunciation.

Comment: Thanks Swami Vishwananda! Yes correct pronunciation is absolutely necessary. But the difficult part is finding a competent person. Still I got a YouTube link of Swami Mukkur where he himself chants this mantra. The link is included in my question. The main question is what is the correct procedure or process to chant this particular mantra. Please advice with proof from Sastra.

Comment: I have only got good comments about Swami Mukkur. So I trust his video and also I have proof from Narasimha tapani Upanishad that words used by him is correct and also God knows everything about us. So he will not be angry even if by mistake we chant his Mantra with wrong pronunciation. Although this is not possible with this mantra as the words are very simple and easy to pronounce.

Comment: Please note that the screenshot in my question explains the places where the words are there in Mantra and its effects if one knows the words of the Mantra and the words are also there. That is the reason the paragraph is quite long. The Mantra is written in my question to get more clarity.

Comment: Dont have fear about wrong chanting or process. It may give less or no result but not bad results.

Comment: @Rakesh: Thanks, I think you are correct because God knows our limitations. Still I keep the question open for more answers.

Comment: @SudevMuraleedharan are you willing to travel to get initiation ?

Comment: @SudevMuraleedharan Do not extend your discussion in the comments. Comments are not for discussion. We are Stack Exchange  not a discussion forum. Do not answer too chatty questions like "Where do you live?" "How are you?" "Did you get initiation before" etc.,  I agree with swami Vishwananda, everything can't be taught on the internet.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Thanks for the alert. I will surely not answer chatty questions. I am using this forum only because I need to get proper answer for my question. I don't have a Guru and there is no Narasimha god temple in my city or even state. But I am going to search with other temple priests as well.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I don't agree with your comment-"Everything can't be taught on the internet" because it is not the medium that is important, it is the learning urge, curiosity, bhakti or devotion is important. There are people who are not lucky like us but they still learn and do bhakti with whatever they have. I have this medium so I am using it to gain knowledge and wisdom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am writing the answer as i have promised to do so to you in the chat room. But i think you'll be disappointed overall.

My answer is based on the Tantrasara. I have the 7th edition of the book.

[ If you want to know about the book or it's author Sri Krishnanada Agamvagis, then see [this page](https://www.revolvy.com/main/index.php?s=Krishnananda%20Agamavagisha). The author was an adept in Vedas and Tantras and he lived about 500 years ago in Bengal's Navadwip town. He traveled all over India and compiled his Tantrasara. It is the possibly the largest compendium work done on Tantras and Agamas. It is completely in Sanskrit, much later it was translated into Bengali by Rasikmohana Chattopaddhyaya. If you see [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22635/4732) then Sir John Woodruffe is citing it, my answer there also citing from it. The book quotes from hundreds of Tantric and Agamic scriptures, some of which are not available at present as  whole texts. Other works of this genre are the PrAnatoshini, SAradatilakam etc but TantrasAra is much more extensive and voluminous]

Because, the procedure is supposedly found in a Vaishnava Agama, so it is not advisable for anyone to chant this Mantra without initiation.

Moreover, the full procedures that are involved will appear to you as cumbersome, if you do not already know about how to perform NyAsas and other stuffs.

Anyways, first of all the correct Mantra in full is this:

> उग्रं वीरं महाविष्णुं ज्वलन्तं सर्वतोमुखं । नृसिंहं भीषणं भद्रं
>   मृत्युमृत्युं नमाम्यहं ।।

So, the devotee should chant this and not the one which is found in the image in your question.

I have divided the answer into points (quoting from TantrasAra's pp 269):

### 1. RishiyAdi NyAsa:

All Mantras have limbs or Angas like DevatA, Chandah, Rishih etc. If someone chants a Mantra without having the knowledge of these limbs, then such a chanting is considered as Anga-HinA or devoid of limbs. Such chanting is not said to bear fruit.

So, first we need to know those limbs for this 32-letterd Mantra. It is said for this Mantra that:

> Ugram viram mahavishnum jvalanatam...  namAmahye.
>
> Aya mantro mAyA putito bhavati tadA sarvArtha kAma phalapradah |

OR if the MAyA Bijam (Hrim) is added before and after the Mantra in the chant, then it fulfills all wishes of the devotee.

After doing PrAtakritya and Vishnu PujA, one chants this Mantra.

> Shirasi brahmane rishaye namaha mukhe anushtupchandase namaha hride
>   nrisimhAya devatAyai namaha

From which we find that Brahma is the Rishih for the Mantra, Anushtupa the Chandah and Nrisimha the DevatA.

When we say "Shirasi brahmane rishaye namaha" we should touch the head with Tattva MudrA. Similarly when we say "mukhe anushtupchandase namaha" we should touch likewise our upper lips.. and the DevatA NyAsa is done in the heart.. These are called the RishiyAdi NyAsas.

### 2.Kara-AngAdi NyAsas:

This is done for purifying our body and hands, by invoking God-principle within our own body. So, we are making Nrisimha literally to come into our body. His hands are invoked in our hands and likewise for other body parts.

Because in Tantras it is said, that one can not worship God without becoming God himself.

These NyAsas are done in the following manner for this particular Mantra:

> Ugram viram-angushtabhyAm namaha.. Mahavishnum-tarjanibhyam namaha..
>   Jvalanta sarvatamukham- madhyAbhyA vashat.... Nrishimham bhishana
>   anamikAbhyA hum...  namAmyaha-astrAya phat...

Thereafter AngAdi NyAsas are done similarly.

### 3. Mantra NyAsa & DhyAnam

This NyAsa is done with Mantras like-

> Right eye-bim namaha, left eye-ram namaha, face-mam namaha, right
>   armpit-hAm namaha, etc....

Then comes DhyAnam which is basically reciting some Sloka peculiar to the Deitry. This is said to bring the Deity immediately to the place where the chanting is done. Sometimes, it is not even advisable to do Japa without reciting the DhyAna Sloka first.

> MAnikyAdri samaprabham nijaruchA samtrastar rakshoganam
>   jAnunyastakarAmbujam trinayanam ratnollasadbhushanam|   ..(not the full DhyAnam)

The meaning of the DhyAnam is roughly this:

> Nrisimha's body's complexion is like that of a mountain made of
>   precious jewels. And that glow is terrifying the demons. His hands are
>   resting on the thighs. He has three eyes and the body is decked with
>   clothing made with Ratnas. His two hands are holding the Shankha and
>   the Chakra. The face is terrifying because of the teeth and the
>   tongue, which is coming out and which looks like a flame of fire. Half
>   of his body is that of a lion and the other half is that of human.
>   ....

After meditating on Lord Nrisimha thus, the devotee has to offer mental worship to him (MAnasopAchAra PujA).

Then he has to do Pitha PujA, Avarana PujA (that is done on the Nrisimha Yantra) and ShadAnga PujA like this:

> MahAvishnum shirase swAhA|
>  Jvalantan sarvatomukham shikhAyai vaushat|
>   Nrisimham bhishanam kavachAya hum |... etc

This PujA must end with Dhupa, Visarjana etc..

> Asya purashcharanam dvAtrimsallakshajapah |
>
> TathAcha- Varnalaksham japenmantram tat sahasram ghritaplutaih|
>   PAyasAnnaih prajuhuyA dvidhivat pujitehanale ||

OR

> For PuraschArana of the Mantra one should do 32 lakhs of Japa and
>   thereafter 1/10-th of that number of oblations are to be offered in
>   the Homa. Oblation should be of Ghee made PAyasam.

The Brahma SamhitA have a Trailokya Vijaya Nrisimha Kavacha, which is comprised around this 32-lettered Mantra (this is found in TantrasAra's pp 591).

The Viniyogah of this Kavacha begins like:

> TrailokyavijayasyApi kavachasya prajApatih rishih chandashcha gAyAtri
>   nrisimha devAta vibhuhu |
>  Khroum bijam me shirah pAtu chandravarno
>   mahAmanuhu |
>  Ugram viram mahAvishnum jvalantam sarvatomukham ||
>
> ..
>
> Iti BrahmasamhitAyAm trailokyavijayam nAma nrisimha kavacham sampAptam
>   ||

This made me to think that the Mantra is also found in the Brahma SamhitA, but the author does not mention the source.

He simply says this:

> Athah Nrisimha Mantraha | Nivandhe- then he mentions the Mantra...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. But I can't find the above details in Brahma Samhita. I request you to let me know the download option of this version of Brahma Samhita.

Comment: @salvation Ok i will check again the Tantrasara book i am quoting from..may be to due to hurry i did make some mistake..but anyways the Mantra Japa procedure is found in one of the Vaisnava Agamas.. I will update this answer..