Mantras and stotras which can make me fearless
What are some of the stotras which can make me fearless but will instill fear and respect among my enemies.
I am facing many negative people who are trying to destroy or hamper my career and image and make me look the bad guy.
I have many options like the hanuman chalisa , Aditya Hrudayam stotram , and kaal bhairava ashtakam . Which one works the fastest? How does each of them actually work.
Are there any stotras which can do such thing very quickly as I am in a very typical situation .

See this answer --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26601/4732
