# Ways of Mantra chanting

Tags: mantras

It is said that Mantras can be chanted in three ways:

1. aloud (vaikhari);
2. whisper (upamshu japa);
3. in mind, with no sound (manasika Mantra).

It is also said, that for beginners is easier to chant Mantras aloud, but if it disturbs others, then one can whisper Mantra. For those ones with more practice it is also possible to chant Mantra in mind.

My question is - is there any difference if one chants Mantra in one or other way? Is there any influence in result? Or it is all the same and one can chant Mantra on its own preference? Thank you!

Comment: You can see this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22637/4732

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It definitely does have difference, it is said that chanting mantras aloud (vachika japa) will take you more time & efforts to attain what you are seeking as compared to mental chanting (mansika japa).

Quoting excepts from the book written by ***[Om Swami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_Swami)*** titled [The Ancient Science of Mantras: Wisdom of the Sages](https://books.google.ca/books/about/The_Ancient_Science_of_Mantras.html?id=u_M5DwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y):

> ***Vigyan Bhairav Tantra*** states that there are only two types of mantras. They are, one, mantras that are internalized
> ***(citta-yukta-mantra)*** and two, mantras that are uttered ***(dhvani-yukta-mantra)***. When it comes to chanting (japa), the mantras that are internalized are far more effective than those that
> are chanted out loud.
>
> Mantra sadhana, however, is an inward process. Chanting aloud like the
> relentless chirping of a cricket does not take you closer to your
> inner world.
>
> In mantra yoga, all hymns, odes and eulogies to God or your deity can
> be sung out loud as they evoke positive feelings of devotion and
> celebration but mantra chanting is almost always done internally. It
> takes a great deal of practice to chant your mantra internally without
> losing your concentration.

Of all the types of mantra chanting, mental chanting is said to be the most effective way of chanting, but with concentration.

> Mental chanting or ***mansika japa*** is when there’s no external
> sound in your chanting and even your lips don’t move. A common
> misconception is that mental chanting is chanting your mantra loud in
> your mind. That’s not really mansika japa. The correct way to do
> mental chanting is to recall your mantra with concentration, one word
> at a time.
>
> **Mental japa is ten times more effective than the first type of japa.**
> It represents intellectual consciousness (pashyanti). It is important
> to note that the sound it is associated with is called pashyanti,
> means that which is seen (as opposed to spoken). In mental chanting,
> you repeatedly visualize the mantra in your mind’s eye.

But main point to be considered while chanting mantra is the 'faith' with which you chant mantra.