# What is the correct method for Manasik Japa?

Tags: mantras, sadhana, vedic-chanting

How do you actually perform manasik japa? What is the correct method?

Comment: Related -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22632/4732

Answer (score 1):

You do manasa Japa by contemplating the words of the mantra without moving your lips.

**On Japa**

> Learned men say that this is Svadhyaya if one performs the Japa of the
> Vedantic passages, Satarudriya (Vaj. Samhita XVI. 1–66), Pranava (Om)
> etc. It brings about the achievement of Sattva Guna in men.

**Kurma Purana II.11.22**

> There are three types of Svadhyayas viz. Vacika (verbal), Upamsu
> (inaudible muttering) and Manasa (mental), those who know the meaning
> of the Vedas say that the latter ones are better than the earlier
> ones.

**Kurma Purana II.11.23**

> That which involves only the throbbing of lips but the words of which
> are inaudible to others is designated as Upamsu (inaudible Svadhyaya).
> It is better (more efficacious) than vocal Japa.

**Kurma Purana II.11.25**

> **The contemplation of all the words in the proper sequence of words and
> syllables without throbbing of the lips, is called Manasa Japa (mental
> Japa)**.

**Kurma Purana II.11.26**

Comment: What does contemplating mean though? Does it mean you say the mantra out loud in your mind?

Comment: It means silently repeating the mantra without moving any muscle in your face and also thinking of the meaning of the mantra.  Thinking the meaning of the mantra means thinking about the deity while repeating the mantra. Of course this is theory. In practice you try to do your best. The power of God's name is such that you will get some effect even if your japa is imperfect.